# Attribute based access control: what is the resource of a "search" action

Tags: xacml, abac

I want to implement an attribute based access control system.
When I user want to perform a "read" or "update" action, I already knew the resource that this action may affect and can return whether or not the action is allowed. 
However, I do not know what to do with the "search" action, are the resources the search results. If that is the case, how can I check if user can perform an action without actually do the search beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

You get to choose how you model things. Actions are a separate attribute of the action category. The XACML standard even gives you a standard attribute called `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id` which you can use for that.

When I model policies, I tpyically create an *artificial* attribute called `objectType` where the value may be the different types of items I want to control access over e.g.

- medical record
- financial transaction
- document...

I then apply the actions to those object types. For instance I would have a policy that states that

> Doctors can view the medical record of a patient they have a relationship with.

As for search, you have to consider what search means: you can control access to search as a whole. For instance basic users cannot search. Advanced users can search. This is an example of functional access control i.e. controlling access to a function (search).

You can restrict it to a particular object type e.g.

> Doctors can search for medical records

The search results would possibly only contain those the doctor is allowed to view. This means that you've in fact triggered 2 authorization checks: the ability to view and the ability to search.

I hope this helps.